# Inherit props from parent functional component in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

In a functional component I want to access props inherited from the parent functional component. To get an idea what I mean, I have the following snippet:

```js
function MainApp(props) {
    const { classes } = props;
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
                <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                    <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" fontWeight="bold">
                        CashCo
                    </Typography>
                    <ToolbarActions className={classes.toolbarActions} />
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
            <main className={classes.appContent}>
                <PageContent content={content} />
            </main>
        </div>
    );
}

function App(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainApp />}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

I want to pass the `props` argument in the App() function to the MainApp(), such that I don't have to access properties like `props.props.some_property`. How can I do that correctly? Cause passing props like this `<MainApp props={props} />` means I have to access the properties like `props.props.some_property` in MainApp(), that's not what I want. I want to access the props like `props.some_property` in MainApp().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can spread the `App` props onto `MainApp`, this will let you access them like so `props.classes`.

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainApp {...props} />}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you! Can you provide me a reference to the React's official documentation please, or is it common sense?

Comment: @AndaluZ you have to think about props as an object, so each time you're passing a specific value you're actually creating a property on the props object. The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to copy properties from object A into object B, this behaviour has nothing to do with React :)

Comment: They do however cover it in the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
function App(props) {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainApp {...props}/>}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```